# "sitting on the fence" grammar

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

First of all,

I realise that "He's still sitting on the fence about buying the coat" sounds the most natural, but is "He is still sitting on the fence about deciding whether to buy the coat or not" grammatically correct?

Secondly, my main question:

Why is "He is still sitting on the fence to decide whether to buy the coat or not." grammatically incorrect?
Especially in terms of the infinitive (to buy) when used with "sitting on the fence".
And why does it need the preposition (about)?

My first post here so sorry if anything is formatted wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It is illogical as well as ungrammatical.

'Sitting on the fence' means a state of indecision, so your suggestion would be like saying "*he is undecided about whether to decide*".

Your second construction is ungrammatical for the same reason - one is undecided '*on*' or '*about*' something. Your sentence says they are sitting on the fence (undecided) '*to*' decide, which is not an idiomatic preposition aside from anything else.